# OpenJPA Enhancement in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, openjpa, playframework-2.3

We are trying to set up `Play Framework 2.3.3` with `OpenJPA`. We are unable to make Runtime or Build Time enhancement work. OpenJPA works when setting the `RuntimeUnenhancedClasses` property to supported in **persistance.xml**, but that's not recommended for production and is a no-go.
We tried using the `javaagent` JVM parameter with no luck like this:

```
activator -J-javaagent:lib/openjpa-all-2.3.0.jar run.
```

How can the enhancer be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your advice.

Here is the solution for the problem:

https://github.com/kristijanbambir/play-openjpa/blob/master/build.sbt

in buid.sbt should be added this PCEnhancer call

```
lazy val enhance = taskKey[Unit]("Enhances model classes")

enhance <<= (fullClasspath in Runtime, runner, streams).map({(cp, run, s) =>
  // only files from classpath are needed
  val classpath = cp.files
  // any options that need to be passed to the enhancer
  val options = Seq()
  // returns an option of errormessage
  val result = run.run("org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer", classpath, options, s.log)
  // if case of errormessage, throw an exception
  result.foreach(sys.error)
}) triggeredBy(compile in Compile)
```